# Is the Wireframe modifier supposed to connect adjacent vertices even if they are excluded in the Vertex Group?

Tags: vertex-groups, wireframe

*Just some heads up: I'm a beginner.*

I was trying to outline some edges on my model with the wireframe modifier since I thought that was the easiest approach. I used a vertex group to tell the modifier where it can place itself but ran into a problem. Some edges caused the wireframe to connect to ghost vertices, but that seems to have fixed itself when I updated to the latest version of Blender (from *2.92.0* to *2.93.1*). All is good in that regard.

But before I updated I did some debugging and found out something that bothered me.

*It is better if I just show it to you.* In the first image, I am assigning a singular edge to the vertex group that is used by the wireframe modifier.
[image: Assigning the edge to my vertex group]

After applying it, you can clearly see that the wireframe disregards the group selection and additionally connects to adjacent vertices (in this case four of them).
[image: The wireframe being applied to two other vertices]

When I updated to the latest version, I tried the same thing again (but with a cube) and it still persisted, as evident from the screenshot below (only the top front edge has been assigned to the vertex group).
[image: Same wireframe problem with Blender 2.93.1]

**So, what I'm asking is this: Is this normal?**

As a beginner, this seems like it should not be happenning purely because of esthetic reasons. If someone wants to outline a singular edge on a model, only that edge should have the wireframe modifier applied to it instead of branching out to every vertex around it.

But then again, I'm not sure if this is the industry standard of outlining edges in Blender. Perhaps there is a better way of doing this I am not aware of and I'm just using the wrong tool for it.

*(Sorry if this is a duplicate, I searched everywhere and couldn't find a similar post)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireframe modifier uses Vertex Group to define the thickness of created geometry. You probably know, that you can define various weights between 0 and 1, and this will change the thickness of wireframe.

To hide a specific part of the mesh, use Mask modifier:

[image]

Comment: So using a mask in combination with wireframe gives you only the part of the mesh you want and hides everything else. Afterwards you would have to duplicate the object and remove the mask in order to get the effect I want (e.g. a cube with one edge using wireframe). I still don`t know why wireframe branches out like that though.

Comment: You can link data in this 2 objects

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that (linking)?

Comment: Copy object with alt+D instead shift+D